# Insert dynamic input fields into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have successfully add & remove the dynamic input fields. However, I am facing a problem on inserting the input fields' values into my database. Any input on this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Input fields

```
    <div id = "container"> 
        <p class = "origin-box">
            <label for = "Origin">From <span class = "box-number1">:</span></label>
            <input type = "text" name = "Origin" value = "" id = "Origin"/>
             <a class = "add-box" href = "#" name = "addBox"><img src = "Add Button.png" width = "35" height = "35" hspace = "20" vspace = "10" align = "middle"/></a>
        </p>

        <p class = "destination-box">
            <label for = "Destination">To <span class = "box-number2">:</span></label>
            <input type = "text" name = "Destination" value = "" id = "Destination"/>
        </p>
    </div>
```

JQuery for dynamically adding/removing input fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var counter = 1;
var max_fields = 10;
$('.my-form .add-box').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (counter < max_fields){
        counter++;
        $('#container').append(
            '<div><strong>Link #' + counter + '</strong><br />' 
            + '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder = "From" /><a href = "#" class = "remove-box"><img src = "Remove Button.png" height = "35" width = "35" align = "middle"/></a></div><br />' );
    }
});

$('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(e){
    $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
    $(this).parent().slideUp("fast","linear", function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').remove();    //$(this) references the closest <div>
        counter--;
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

After clicked on Submit button.

`<p><input id = "btnSubmit" type = "submit" name= "submit" value = "Submit" /></p>`

SQL statement for data insertion to database's tables.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
     //create instance of database class
$db = new mysqldb();
$db->select_db();
//Check if user has actually added additional fields to prevent a php error
if ($_POST['fields']) {

    //get last inserted userid
    $inserted_user_id = $db->last_insert_id();

    //Loop through added fields
    foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value ) {

        //Insert into transport table
        $sql_transport = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport (Origin) VALUES ('%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($value));  
        $result_transport = $db->query($sql_transport);
        $inserted_transport_id = $db->last_insert_id(); 

        //Insert into mainclaim table
        $sql_mainclaim = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_mainclaim (transportID) VALUES ('%s')",
                               mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_transport_id));  
        $result_mainclaim = $db->query($sql_mainclaim);
    }
} else {    
    //No additional fields added by user
}
//disconnect mysql connection
$db->kill();
}
```

Comment: your if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){  should be if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ since the POST value is checked by input name and not input id

Comment: Enter more information, and also what error you are getting.

Comment: @Epodax: Thanks for catching that, a tired mind often do simple mistakes.

Comment: Your welcome :) And you are most certainly correct, I know of it myself, mind if I post it as an' answer and perhaps harvest some points for it? ;)

Comment: @Epodax Sure buddy, go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
    //Other code
}
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    //Other code
}
```

Since the POST value is found by input name and not input id